# How can I make a procedural jump in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural, lerp

I need to make a procedural jump in a board game in Unity C# (I conditionally have many points where the player has to jump from one to the other with different distances) which is called by the script. I cannot do animation because I need to calculate distance.

I've tried to use `Vector3.Slerp` which is much modified but it does not work like I imagined at all.

[image: Here is modified Slerp]

(There I've made another `Vector3` because I need another axis in the jump)

Ideas ran out.

Please tell me how can I fix a problem in the script above or how I can do procedural jump else. Thank you so much.

Comment: You mean with "Procedural jump" an animation of jumping between multiple points in sequence or distance? 
Looking at your code i see a few issues.
The slerp function returns the value between the start and end position so giving 0.5f will give you a dramatic slow down effect the closer you get to the goal. You probably want something that changes the 0.5f to something going from 0 to 1 like time += Time.deltaTime and use Slerp(startVector, endVector, time) which will actually reach the goal at the end.
But i am unsure what you want to achieve here exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `index` is always ever only to be `0`. And the code you do in `LateUpdate` is fully redundant - simply assign the new position directly to `transform.position`.

I think what you are trying to achieve is to move your object smooth through the various positions provided by `stand` one by one.

So what you need is

- store the current target point
- move smooth towards it
- when reaching the target point

  - previous target point becomes new start point
  - get next target point

and do this until you reach the very last one.

You could e.g. do this in a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) like

```
public float moveSpeed;

public void StartMoveThroughWaypoints(IEnumerable<Vector3> waypoints)
{
    StartCoroutine(MoveThroughWaypoints(waypoints));
}

private IEnumerator MoveThroughWaypoints(IEnumerable<Vector3> waypoints)
{
    foreach(var waypoint in waypoints)
    {
        while(transform.position != waypoint)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, waypoint, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            yield return null;
        }

        // as the "==" above has only a precision of 1e-5
        // ensure to end with a clean position
        transform.position = waypoint;

        // optional add delay to shortly hold on each waypoint
        //yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        // or at least for one frame
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to make a jump (using to axis) not just smooth moving from one point to another (it's just 1 axis).

Comment: In that case you can adjust this using e.g. [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/183507/add-parabola-curve-to-straight-movetowards-movement)